# Create Intenet of an Activity from android class project

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-intent, xamarin.android

I am new to xamarin. My **MyProj.Android** project called android class library project **MyCls** where I am handling the Intent.

basically creating Intent for push notification message

> MyCls contains below function

```
//Setting push notification's intent
public static void CreateIntent(string className)
{
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, MKMessagingServiceConstants.CHANNELID);
    builder.SetContentTitle(title);
    builder.SetContentText(body);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Type.GetType(classname) );
    intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop | ActivityFlags.SingleTop);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.OneShot); 
    builder.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.SetPriority(NotificationCompat.PriorityHigh);
    builder.SetAutoCancel(true); //disappear after sometime
    var notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService);
    notificationManager.Notify(0, builder.Build());

}
```

> MyProj.Android --> MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity: global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
   protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
    
            MyCls.CreateIntent("MyProj.Droid.TestActivity")
   }
}
```

**Problem** : Type.GetType(classname) I am passing the class name of *MyProj.Android* so it wont create (getting value null ).

**Result** : Need to create Intent from *MyCls* that will open an Activity of *MyProj.Android*

Answer (score 0):

sudo() {
case "${1:-}" in
reboot)
echo "Are you REALLY sure you want to do this?"
echo "If so, enter 'sudo r-reboot', and I'll pass it along.";;
r-reboot)
shift
command sudo reboot "$@";;
*)
command sudo "$@"
esac

}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).